# How to make bottom bar ("Windows List" extension ) background black

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I just had to re-install Ubuntu because of a mess I made with NVidia drivers. After re-installation, I noticed that the bottom bar is now grey, not black as before.

Tried to "fix" it by modifying some color valuesi in extension's stylesheet.css to no avail.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like ( ugly! )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to make it black-er, yet a shadow remains.
I went to extension folder, edited `stylesheet.css`, and added `background-color: black;` to `bottom-panel.`